# Round to the nearest 100's palce Mule 4 anypoint studio 7.5

Tags: mule, rounding, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Working with anypoint studio in Mule 4

Is it possible to round numbers to the 100's place?
Example: 12345.6789 -> 12345.68

I have tried this:
round(12345.6789) as Number {format "#.##"}

*I might be looking for information in the wrong place. Here is what I am referencing: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-round*

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from a colleague

12345.6789 as Number as String {format: "#,##0.0#"}

result:
12345.68